# Desire2Learn - How to determine what roles/permissions are needed for rest Api call?

Tags: desire2learn

So, I have a D2L integration using the Rest Api that works whenever I use the userId/userKey for an Administrator, but fails whenever I try to use the userId/userKey for an Instructor account.

Is there a way to determine what permissions are required for each Api Call?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions can vary widely for roles defined in D2L, the best place to check would be the Roles and Permissions page within the D2L instance.  In this case, it sounds like the Administrator account has permission for the action you are trying to call via Valence, while the instructor account does not have that permission.